# android build error with admob plugin

Tags: codenameone

I am trying to build with the latest admobfullscreen plugin and get this.
Removed plugin and build was ok.

Note: I'm also using push notifications if that is any help. Using `google-services.json`.

```
Compiling with source level 1.7 and target level 1.7.
:compileReleaseJavaWithJavac - is not incremental (e.g. outputs have changed, no previous execution, etc.).
file or directory '/tmp/build1851142413066197938xxx/WordTime1/src/release/java', not found
Compiling with JDK Java compiler API.
/tmp/build1851142413066197938xxx/WordTime1/src/main/java/com/codename1/admob/AdMobNativeImpl.java:3: error: package com.google.android.gms.ads does not exist
import com.google.android.gms.ads.*;
^
/tmp/build1851142413066197938xxx/WordTime1/src/main/java/com/codename1/admob/AdMobNativeImpl.java:13: error: cannot find symbol
    private InterstitialAd interstitial;
            ^
  symbol:   class InterstitialAd
  location: class AdMobNativeImpl
/tmp/build1851142413066197938xxx/WordTime1/src/main/java/com/codename1/admob/AdMobNativeImpl.java:66: error: cannot find symbol
        interstitial = new InterstitialAd(activity);
                           ^
  symbol:   class InterstitialAd
```

build hints:

```
codename1.displayName=Word Time
codename1.arg.ios.pods.platform=7.0,7.0
codename1.android.keystoreAlias=alias_name
codename1.arg.ios.no_strip=true
codename1.android.keystorePassword=*********
codename1.ios.provision=
codename1.android.min_sdk_version=8
codename1.arg.ios.dsym=true
codename1.arg.android.release=true
codename1.arg.ios.statusbar_hidden=false
android.playService.ads=true
codename1.languageLevel=5
codename1.android.keystore=/Users/sam/d...store/cn1.ks
codename1.vendor=Haptic Apps LLC
codename1.arg.xxx=dfsdfwef
codename1.arg.win.ver=8
codename1.ios.certificatePassword=
codename1.arg.ios.unsafe=true
codename1.ios.debug.certificatePassword=
codename1.mainName=WordTime1
codename1.arg.android.enableProguard=true
codename1.ios.debug.certificate=
codename1.arg.android.proguardKeep=-kee...dia.**
codename1.arg.ios.application_exits=false
codename1.secondaryTitle=Word Time
codename1.description=
codename1.ios.debug.provision=
codename1.arg.build.incSources=1
codename1.arg.j2me.nativeThemeConst=0
codename1.rim.certificatePassword=
codename1.version=1.14
codename1.ios.certificate=
codename1.icon=icon.png
codename1.rim.signtoolCsk=
codename1.arg.android.debug=false
codename1.rim.signtoolDb=
codename1.arg.ios.includePush=true
codename1.arg.ios.testFlight=false
codename1.packageName=com.hapticapps.wordtime
codename1.android.targetSDKVersion=14
```

## cause of compilation error

I found the issue is due to: google-services.json being added for push notifications causes the admob plugin to fail. Cannot have both in the build as it is causing some build misconfigurations.

This is not a solution, just identifies the cause.

Comment: How did you install the cn1lib? What's in your build hints? Specifically I'd like to know the build hints specific to Andorid

Comment: I installed the cn1lib a few years back.  I needed to update to use google-services.json.  I updated the cn1libs and that did not fix this issue.

Comment: I added the build hints

Answer (score 0):

You have an old build hint that could be seriously damaging: `android.targetSDKVersion=14`. It should be removed. However as a word of warning:

The default SDK version is `23` which changed a lot of things specifically permissions. It might break a lot of things and once you submit an app with a higher SDK version Google blocks you from downgrading to the older SDK version!

So make sure you test your app REALLY well before you do that.

Comment: Still has same error:  package com.google.android.gms.ads does not exist

Comment: Check that the build hint didn't return. I'm assuming it did. If so which cn1libs are you using and are they at the latest version?

Comment: I found the issue is due to: google-services.json  being added for push notifications causes the admob plugin to fail.   Cannot have both in the build as it is causing some build misconfigurations.

Comment: Are you sure you are using the latest cn1lib version of ads?  It looks like you added build hints manually such as this: `android.playService.ads=true` and that uses incorrect syntax that's ignored. The latest cn1lib should add this automatically

Comment: I am using the latest AdmobFullScreen.cn1lib plugin.  Is this the one you are referring to?

Comment: Well I created a new hello world app, set it to 3.8.  
Added google-services.json in the android directory.   
Opened the properties and added android.googleAdUnitId=myid.   
This still gets the 'com.google.android.gms.ads' error. 
Removing either one will work.  But they do not work together.
This is as basic as I can get.

Comment: Thanks, can you file an issue on this so I can assign it and we don't lose track of it? http://github.com/codenameone/CodenameOne/issues/new
It helps if you file it and reference this discussion in the issue so we'll be able to see the full history of the discussion. Thanks

Comment: I am currently facing the same issue. I just added the AdmobFullScreen.cn1lib and my build fails after hours of debugging i realized Admob cannot exist with push notifications and location services. I can only keep one. I think it has to do with the version of google play service being used. Shai kindly point me to the solution to this. since it was posted 2yrs ago

Comment: We need to probably fix the cn1lib but I'm not versed enough in this to give you a complete answer.

Comment: When you file the issue, can you paste the full error log?  There may be details in there that shed light.